# How can I display data of a list entry via a macro in Apache Freemarker?

Tags: html, freemarker

Im using the templating engine freemarker (v. 2.3.31) with java/spring.
Goal: In my <#list></#list> I would like render data for each dog via a **macro** that is defined in another file (dog-detail.html.ftl).

```
<#import "../base/templates/dog-detail.html.ftl" as detail>
...

<div class="content">
    <label>${(data.title)!""}</label>

    <#if (data.dogs)?has_content>
        <#list (data.dogs) as dog >

          <label>inside dog detail</label>

            <@detail.detail dog?index+1 />

        </#list>
        <#else>
        <label>no dogs here ...</label>
    </#if>
</div>
```

**dog-detail.html.ftl:**

```
<#macro detail index>

    <label>Hello I am the ${index}. dog. My name is ${(dog.name)!""} i am ${(dog.age)!""} years old</label>

</#macro>
```

**my json:**

```
{
  "title": "hello i am a title",
  "dogs": [
    {
      "name": "Bello",
      "age": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "Bella",
      "age": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Woof",
      "age": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

**The output:**

```
<div class="content">
  <label>hello i am a title</label>
  <label>inside dog detail</label>
  <label>Hello I am the 1. dog. My name is  i am  years old</label>
  <label>inside dog detail</label>
  <label>Hello I am the 2. dog. My name is  i am  years old</label>
  <label>inside dog detail</label>
  <label>Hello I am the 3. dog. My name is  i am  years old</label>
</div>
```

I never had trouble accessing data in a macro, yet whenever I try to access an entry in a list within a macro it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

I tried to pass the whole "dog" as a param to the macro, this did not work as freemarker seems not to be able to handle whole json nodes as params.

**Current Work Around**

When the index is passed to the macro, the data can be accessed like so: `${(data.dogs[index-1].name)!""}` .

Comment: Not related to your problem, just some notes. `dog?index - 1` can be written as `dog?counter`. You don't need the `#if`/`#else` as `#list` itself can contain an `#else`. `(data.title)!""` can be written as just `data.tile!` (unless you actually expect `data` itself missing). There are other unnecessary `()`-s elsewhere too, like in `<#list (data.dogs) as dog>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in my macro my variables work when I call them with their full json path, example: `data.title`.  However, the expression `data.dogs[index].name` still did not work for some reason. I am guessing it is because the place I am calling it from (inside the dogs list)

In the meantime, I had a look at the namespace documentation and found a work around:

```
.data_model.data.dogs[index].name
```

This enabled me to access the dog respectively its properties without having to pass the entire dog as json

Answer (score 0):

The macro needs access to the `dog` variable; however, only the index is passed. Change the macro to include said variable:

```
<#macro detail index dog>

    <label>Hello I am the ${index}. dog. My name is ${(dog.name)!""} i am ${(dog.age)!""} years old</label>

</#macro>
```

And pass the dog as a parameter from the main template file like this:

```
<@detail.detail dog?index+1 dog/>
```

Comment: That would be a really neat way, if it worked.
Unfortunately, I can't pass dog as variable because it is a JsonNode, the renderer crashes with a parsing exception.

Comment: @Chira If `dog.name` fails, that has nothing to do with `#list` or `#macro`. You need to configure FreeMarker to use an `ObjectWrapper` that recognizes `JsonNode`, otherwise FreeMarker will have no idea how to get the `name` from it, and you can only use the Java API of `JsonNode` in templates (maybe that will require using `?api` as well).

Comment: @Chira But actually, you said that `data.dogs[index].name` works, so then `dog.name` must too. You do some other mistake there.

Comment: @ddekany yes, I am passing an object wrapper to my model when I create it: `SimpleHash model = new SimpleHash(objectWrapper);`. Afterwards, I pass the JsonNode to the model `model.put("data", jsonNode);` So, yeah I am still puzzled on why this does not work.

Comment: @Chire So then `data.dogs[index].name` actually didn't work? Anyway, if it's a Jackson `JsonNode` object, then the problem is that FreeMarker out-of-the-box doesn't know the Jackson API. That's where the proper `ObjectWrapper` comes into the picture. Maybe someone already created one that knows Jackson; I'm not sure.